# Retrieving a webpage that requires loading time

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup, html

I'm using Jsoup to parse the content from a website. The problem is that there are some data on the page that requires a couple of seconds to load. For this reason, my program can only get the loading graphic rather than the loaded data. Here is what I got:

```
<div class="sidebar_section">
    <h3><a href="#" class="sidebar_toggle down">Counsel</a></h3>
        <ul style="display:none;" id="counsel">
            <li>Loading &nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="/members/images/ajax-loader3.gif" /></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

If I open this url in a browser, I can actually see the contents for this block rather than the "loading" word.

I was wondering if there is anyway to get the content after the page is fully loaded. Here is my simple code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
```

Any help is really really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[HttpURLConnection](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/how-open-url-read-contents-httpurl-connection-java) may be a better method for grabbing a web page as it gives more control and error handling, plus you can get the MIME type and character encoding.